Generalized Lambert W Function?
The Lambert W Function (defined as the inverse of $x e^x$) is implemented in Mathematica as ProductLog.
Has anyone made any progress implementing the Generalized Lambert W Function defined as the inverse of
$$
e^x a \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}
$$
where $P$ and $Q$ are monic polynomials. Analogously to the Meijer G Function this function depends on $a$ and the zeroes of $P$ and $Q$.
Maignan, Aude; Scott, T. C. (2016). "Fleshing out the Generalized Lambert W Function". SIGSAM. 50 (2): 45–60.
T. C. Scott, G. J. Fee, and J. Grotendorst. Numerics of Generalized Lambert W function. SIGSAM, 48(2):42–56, November 2014.

M'y dream for sure but not yet as far as I know

This probably should go to Math.SE.
